# How can I recover a recently expired BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

A table I had been updating every day disappeared, and I found out it may have expired. I hadn't taken notice of it.

Is there a simple way to recover that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is within 7 days, you may be able to fetch the data using time-travel:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#for_system_time_as_of

And once you are able to read the data, you can save the result to a destination table as kind of a way to recover the table.